# Automatically mount a drive using /etc/fstab, and limiting access to all users of a specific group

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab

I currently have an extra HDD which I am using as my workspace. I am trying to get it to mount automatically on reboots using the following line added to /etc/fstab

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/workspace auto defaults 0 1
```

This works to auto mount it, however I would like to restrict read/write access to users belonging to a specific group. How would I go about doing this in /etc/fstab? Can I simply just use ***chown*** or ***chmod*** to control the access?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If the filesystem type is one that doesn't have permissions, such as FAT, you can add `umask`, `gid` and `uid` to the fstab options. For example:

```
 /dev/sdb1 /media/workspace auto defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022 0 1
```

`uid=1000` is the user id.

`gid=1000` is the group id.

`umask=022` this will set permissions so that the owner has read, write, execute. Group and Others will have read and execute.

To see your changes you do not need to reboot. Just `umount` and `mount` again without arguments. For example:

```
umount /media/workspace
mount  /media/workspace
```

But make sure to do not have any process (even your shell) using that directory.

Comment: You can asign to uid and gid as users and groups in text mode

Comment: @krt, What if the filesystem type is NOT one that doesn't have permissions such as FAT?

Answer (score 8):

I would gate access to the filesystem through a directory that contains the mount point.

As root:

```
mkdir -p /media/group1only/workspace
chgrp group1 /media/group1only
chmod 750 /media/group1only
```

This is full access to root and read+execute access for members of group1. Don't give them write access here, since if they accidentally rename the `workspace` mount point, it could make your system fail to boot.

And add this to /etc/fstab :

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/group1only/workspace auto defaults 0 1
```

After the filesystem is mounted, you can make further ownership and mode changes to objects within the filesystem to accommodate finer-grain access among the group members.

Comment: This recipe does not work. After mounting the properties for `/media/group1only/workspace` are `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 apr 13 09:05 workspace`. Thus `group1only` does not play any role for the mount point.

Comment: @JohnSmith This should work fine. On Linux you need execute permissions on *all* parent directories in order to access a child, and this is the role `group1only` plays. Even if the permissions are 766 on `workspace`, users without the required permissions for the 750-permissioned parent directory will get permission denied. Try this in a non-root shell by `cd`ing to / and attempting to end `workspace`.

Answer (score 2):

For example, assuming the filesystem on the disk supports ACL's, and using the hypothetical user, myusername, and the hypothetical group for accessing the disk, diskusers, something like the following could be done. `$` indicated a command executed as a regular user; `#` indicates a command executed as the user, root.

Create a group to which a user may belong for the purpose.

```
$ sudo groupadd diskusers
$ sudo usermod -a -G diskusers myusername
$ logout
```

Log in again.

```
$ sudo -i
# mount /media/workspace
# chown root:root /media/workspace
# chmod 0750 /media/workspace/
# setfacl -d -m -g:diskusers:7 /media/workspace
# setfacl -m g:diskusers:7 /media/workspace
```

The "7" in the `setfacl` command is octal (read = 4 + write = 2 + execute = 1),
much like normal octal permissions (0400, 0200, 0100).

The `-d` is a switch to specify a default mask - new files and directories.
The `-m` is the mask to apply to the directory.

You also could apply the mask to all files initially after setting the default (above):

```
find /media/workspace -exec setfacl -m g:diskusers:7 {} +
```

At that point, only root and members of diskusers can access the files. I like Mark Plotnick's idea, too, about applying permissions to a subdirectory. This technique could be used that way, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'am on ubuntu 22.04

My root mount in fstab is like this:

```
UUID=myuuid /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,user=owner    0       1
```

So, I don't have aa owner user into passwd conf file, but i think this owner is the absolute owner of the mount point (directory) ...

- `/` has root *owner*
- `/home/whateveruser` has `whateveruser` *owner*
- `/media/myuser/mypendrive` has `myuser` *owner*

We don't need to specify user=listofusers. Owner is sufficient to get root and effective logged user(s).

My usb 3.0 pendrive is getting almost 200 MB transfer rate, after i set user=owner at / ext4 mount point.

I don't know if that works like I said, but I can boot with no mount errors nor `systemd` errors.